# How to get the union of two AR relation objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say I have 2 AR queries:

```
users = User.where(...)
users = [user1, user2, user3]
```

and

```
users = User.some_complicated_query
users = [user3, user4, user5]
```

Say I want the method to return:

```
all_users = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5]
```

How do I do this union? I'm on Rails 4 so I don't have `or`.

I want user 3 to be unique and not duplicated in the final set.

The docs on [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) aren't great but I don't think this is what I want right?

Comment: how about using union operation on arrays `users` and `admin_users`; and return it like `users | admin_users`

Comment: Try something like User.where(first condition).or(User.where(your admin_users condition)). The or method is new to Rails 5. If it gives you duplicates they tack on .distinct at the end.

Comment: @Jwan622 Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
total_users = users1 | users2
```

Or

```
total_users = (users1 + users2).uniq
```

Should most probably do the trick. Similar to @Iceman's solution but it spawns an extra query which i am not in favour of.

Also, try

```
users1 = User.where(...)
users2 = User.some_complicated_query.where.not(id: users1.pluck(:id))
new_users = users1 + users2
```

Comment: But I need to return an AR relation, not an array.

Comment: The controller that this query is called in has a bunch of logic like `ActiveRelation.each {|thing| thing.order_id}` and so I'm trying to keep the output to the controller the same so I don't have to change any logic.

Comment: well, `thing.order_id` is still achievable in array..try running the code once

Answer (score 1):

> But I need to return an AR relation, not an array. – Jwan622

As @SteveCarey suggested, you could get the union by this:

```
users1 = User.where(...)
users2 = User.some_complicated_query

all_users = users1 | users2
```

Then do an extra query to get the AR relation:

```
all_users = User.where(id: all_users)
```

---

But using `or` will make it simpler. (Upgrade to Rails 5 or install [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or) gem to use `or`)

```
all_users = users1.or(users2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what these queries actually are and how they overlap. If you're looking for users that fit *either* condition, you'll want to use `or`, as @SteveCarey suggested:

```
regular_users = User.not_admins
admin_users = User.admins
all_users = regular_users.or(admin_users)
```

This isn't going to execute a SQL `UNION`, though the result is going to be the same in these examples. You would only need a proper `UNION` if you were joining data from multiple subqueries, in which case you can [use Arel](https://makandracards.com/bonyiii/24302-activerecord-union-with-arel) to handle this.

Note that this is quite different from Ruby's own union operator, which preserves only items in both sets of objects being unioned. If you're looking for that behavior, you would combine the scopes:

```
User.not_admins.admins
```

In this case, as you can see, it's not going to be very useful. ;)

Other situations:

For cases where you're looking at comparing against associated models, you can get pretty far with `references(:other_things).merge(OtherThing.condition)`.

If you're looking to return data from two similar objects that are stored in different tables, you should consider using [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) to enable ActiveRecord to instantiate the correct object types when you pull results.

If you want data from two unrelated objects, but you want to coalesce the data for presentation or similar, you really want to execute two queries and merge the results in Ruby:

```
posts = Posts.recent
events = Events.recent
news_feed_items = Set.new(posts) + events
news_feed_items.sort_by { |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```